# Easil js - mouse events not firing on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a threesixty app - and the navigation code works fine for other browsers. I am unable to figure out why its not firing on IE.

```
   addNavigation: function () {
        var self = this;

        self.stage.onMouseOver = function (event) {
            self.setCursor("pointer");
        }

        self.stage.onMouseDown = function (event) {
            self.start_x = event.rawX;
            self.stage.onMouseMove = self.mouseMoved;


            self.stage.onMouseMove = function (event) {
                var dx = event.rawX - self.start_x;
                var abs_dx = Math.abs(dx);

                if(abs_dx > 5) {
                    self.update360(dx / abs_dx);
                    self.start_x = event.rawX;
                }
            }

            self.stage.onMouseUp = function (event) {
                self.stage.onMouseMove = null;
                self.stage.onMouseUp = null;
                self.setCursor("pointer");
                superviewHander.changeOnStage(this, self.currentFrame);
            }

            self.setCursor("w-resize");
        }

        this.cursor = "auto";
    }
```

Comment: This is the jsfiddle - but this doesn't appear to work in IE. http://jsfiddle.net/e4vLyt5n/7/

Comment: Seems like you fiddle is broken. Nothing is getting displayed. Could you please check it and let us know. Thanks.

Comment: Upgrade to jQuery 2.1.3 and your demo at least shows up in IE. However, you seem to have a cross-origin request problem. Try serving all your files from the same server.

Comment: Is there a soluton to the mouse events

Comment: If this is happening in IE 9 than you can check this https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/686 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665690/easel-js-security-restrictions-on-localhost-machine If you will try loading images from local machine or from the same domain where your webpage is using this script than it may work. Let me know if it still not working

Comment: Works like a charm in IE if using jQuery (edge)

Comment: Do you guys have a jsfiddle of it working in lower versions of IE. I did pull this down locally and get it working in IE10 - but not in edge. Is there a better way of refactoring the code to control the cursors in the canvas?